# Hydrogen atom- Eigenvalue/function relation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, operators, eigenvalue

I have been given the following Question:

---

The energy eigenstates of the atomic electron are usually described by wave
functions $ψ_{nℓm}(r)$.
Relate each of $n, ℓ,$ and $m$ to the eigenvalue of a specific operator by giving
the eigenvalue equation for this operator acting on $ψ_{nℓm}(r)$.

---

I understand the following eigenvalue/function relations:
$$\hat{\vec{L}^2} Y_{ℓm}=\hbar^2 ℓ(ℓ+1) Y_{ℓm}.$$
and;
$$\hat{L_z} Y_{ℓm}=\hbar m Y_{ℓm}.$$
But I don't understand where the principle quantum number, $n$ comes into things. If someone could explain, that'd be great. Thanks.

Comment: Oh my! Try Hamiltonian $\hat{H}$.

Comment: $n$ is inside the radial part of the eigenfunction. When you been through the solution process for the hydrogen atom (separation of variables in the Schrodinger equation), you'll see the role of $n$.

Comment: can you please tell me why you took off the favourite from my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

n is for the energy of the electron, the eigenvalue of the Hamiltonian. It is called principal, because it should be the basic being related to energy.

It is n because it is natural, in the case of H, it is En=-13.6eV/n^2.

$$\sum_{\ell=0}^{\ell=n-1}(2\ell + 1)= n^2$$

It was first used with Bohr H atom, he used n for the quantization of angular momentum, as n the allowed orbit.

$L = n{h \over 2\pi} = n\hbar$

But the n you are talking about is the solution of the Schrodinger equation for H. This n that you get by solving the Schrodinger equation is the allowed energy state.

> Hamilton's equations in classical Hamiltonian mechanics have a direct analogy in quantum mechanics. Suppose we have a set of basis states { | n ⟩ } , which need not necessarily be eigenstates of the energy. For simplicity, we assume that they are discrete, and that they are orthonormal, i.e.,

```
⟨ n ′ | n ⟩ = δ n n ′
```

> Note that these basis states are assumed to be independent of time. We will assume that the Hamiltonian is also independent of time.
>
> The instantaneous state of the system at time t, | ψ ( t ) ⟩  , can be expanded in terms of these basis states:

```
| ψ ( t ) ⟩ = ∑ n a n ( t ) | n ⟩
```

> where

```
a n ( t ) = ⟨ n | ψ ( t ) ⟩ .
```

Please look at Hamilton's equations in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_(quantum_mechanics)